# Additional option in Column Validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, column-validation

I have a a validation that only accepts a specific format of 6numbers followed by a dash and further 6 numbers as below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(FAQ),TRUE,AND(LEN(FAQ)=13,MID(FAQ,7,1)="-",ISNUMBER(MID(FAQ,1,6)+0),LEN(TRIM(MID(FAQ,1,6)))=6,ISNUMBER(MID(FAQ,8,6)+0),LEN(TRIM(MID(FAQ,8,6)))=6))
```

This works perfectly, however I have to add a further condition that can be entered and this is the phrase 'Not Required'.

Basically the validation will still accept a blank field, a Not required or numbers is the specific format as current formula.

How to I go to add this condition?

Comment: What is the new condition?

Comment: Your resultant function is likely going to be another IF statement superimposed over the existing function you gave in your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please use the below formula:**

```
=OR(ISBLANK(FAQ),FAQ="Not Required",AND(LEN(FAQ)=13,MID(FAQ,7,1)="-",ISNUMBER(MID(FAQ,1,6)+0),LEN(TRIM(MID(FAQ,1,6)))=6,ISNUMBER(MID(FAQ,8,6)+0),LEN(TRIM(MID(FAQ,8,6)))=6))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the same formula as given in my answer, right?

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I need to wrap the columns name in square brackets []

Comment: Hi mtagliaferri. I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=OR(ISBLANK([FAQ]), [FAQ]="Not Required", AND(LEN([FAQ])=13,MID([FAQ],7,1)="-",ISNUMBER(MID([FAQ],1,6)+0),LEN(TRIM(MID([FAQ],1,6)))=6,ISNUMBER(MID([FAQ],8,6)+0),LEN(TRIM(MID([FAQ],8,6)))=6))
```

More cleaner (same formula):

```
=OR(ISBLANK(FAQ), FAQ = "Not Required", AND(LEN(FAQ) = 13, MID(FAQ, 7, 1) = "-", ISNUMBER(MID(FAQ, 1, 6) + 0), LEN(TRIM(MID(FAQ, 1, 6))) = 6, ISNUMBER(MID(FAQ, 8, 6) + 0), LEN(TRIM(MID(FAQ, 8, 6))) = 6))
```

Comment: I get an error with this code

Comment: Did you get the syntax error message? I have just tried this with first two conditions in "OR" & it is working fine for me.

Comment: What is the error message? Did you try it again? It is working at my end.